# How to use g_timeout_add?

Tags: c, button, timeout, gtk

I am making a program in C with GTK and Glade for a serial communication. I am having problem using g_timeout_add. For example I have a function `serial_data()` which contain my serial data and I have a button handler `on_update_button_clicked()`. So till now I have done that if `update button` is clicked, `gtk_timeout` should run. But it running just for one time.

```
on_update_button_clicked(GtkButton *Update_Button)
{
     //2nd argument is serial_data function which contain actual data    
     g_timeout_add(250,serial_data,NULL); 
}
```

where I am missing the point?

I have another button `stop button`. So i want that `timeout` should stop when `stop button handler` is clicked. How to do that.??

One more question to ask, I want to count the number of times `timeout` is running like a counter. So that I can display the numbers of counter. How is this possible.?
Please help thanks.

Comment: One question per post please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`g_timeout_add()` returns an event source id that you should store. You can use `g_source_remove()` with that id in your stop button handler to stop the timeout.

Comment: how to check for that id of g_timeout_add()??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You get the value like any function return value... `source_id = g_timeout_add (250, timeout_func, NULL);`

Comment: @jku above doesn't answer for the OP's initial question. How to use g_timeout_add(). Have you figured out how to get this work? then answer or edit OP's question.

Comment: The post contains lots of questions... I would probably have answered in more detail if the question had had more details -- as an example it could have had the actual timeout handler function implementation. Without those details I can't even edit the OP's question: how could I know what the problem in his code is? If you have a specific question about g_timeout_add() please post it as a new question with example code.

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation, *The function is called repeatedly until it returns FALSE*. You can call `on_update_button` with a boolean argument to toggle the timeout call from being continually called, set it running when argument evaluates to `TRUE`, and delete the thread with `g_source_remove(threadID)` if argument is `FALSE`. Here's a demonstration:

```
// compiling with:  gcc test.c `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -o test
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib/gi18n.h>

guint threadID = 0;
guint serial_counter = 0;

static gboolean
serial_data (gpointer user_data)
{
    // do something
    printf("counter: %d\n", serial_counter);
    serial_counter++;
    return user_data;
}

static void
on_update_button_clicked (GtkButton* button, gpointer user_data)
{
    if (user_data == 1)
    {
        threadID = g_timeout_add(250, serial_data, user_data);
    }
    else if (user_data == 0)
    {
        g_source_remove(threadID);
        threadID = 0;   
    }
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget *update_button;
    GtkWidget *stop_button;
    GtkWidget *box;

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "test.c");

    box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);

    update_button = gtk_button_new_with_label (_("Update"));
    stop_button = gtk_button_new_with_label (_("Stop"));

    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box), update_button, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box), stop_button, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), box);

    g_signal_connect (update_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (on_update_button_clicked), 1);
    g_signal_connect (stop_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (on_update_button_clicked), 0);
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

check the developer site

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add

its quite explicit.

you can have a `gpointer` to a `gboolean STOP`, finish the `serial_data` func in `return STOP`, and make your `stop button` change that `STOP = FALSE` and it will stop calling on that function. Or something like that.

Comment: better to change STOP by CONTINUE 'cause CONTINUE=FALSE make more sense.